# Passing actual arguments in mockito stubbing

Tags: mockito, junit4, stubbing

For a case in which stubbed variable in made inside the actual production code,
How can we pass actual arguments with stubbing e.g using Mockito.when in JUnits?

E.g if a method in production code is like:

1) `servicaClass.doSomething(Calendar.getInstance)`

2) `servicaClass.doSomething(someMethodToCreateActualVariable())`

while testing how a actual parameter can be passed?
Like

-> `when(mockedServiceClass.doSomething(Calendar.geInstance)).thenReturn("")`

But while testing production code will take its own calendar value while executing.

There can be a way to make public setter getter method for the used variable to be stuffed. But that dont seem to be a optimum solution.

Any pointers with this regard will be helpful?

Comment: Wouldn't simply using `Mockito.any( Calendar.class )` do the trick for you? If you need it more complex, you can use an Answer object instead of the simple return value to allow more specific reactions to various input parameters...

Comment: Dont want to use any() matcher(want to test with actual parameters). I have seen Answer also, but not sure how it will pass the required parameter in actual code to test.

Comment: If the actual parameters are created on the fly, like `Calendar.getInstance()`, `Matchers` are your best chance. You could try `Mockito.eq(...)`. And `Answer` simply gets an `InvocationMock` object from which you can get the actual parameter objects.

Comment: Yes, still not able to manipulate the parameters used on the fly. Mockito.any() is only helping the cause. Answer or ArgumentCaptor can only let me know which parameters were used at runtime. Need to check some way if any?

Comment: Honestly, now I have no idea what you want to do and why. please explain.

Comment: OK. It is like if i call Mockito.when(someService.someMethod(Calendar.getInstance)).thenReturn(someThing);

In actual code it will be someMethod(Calendar.getInstance).

So how can I test the line without using Any()/Matcher?

Comment: No clue, if the method call returns different (and not equal) instances each time. What do you need that for any why can't you simply use any?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the matching value *before the fact*, you can use stubbing. Mockito matchers like `eq` (compare with `equals`) and `same` (compare with `==`) will help there, or you can get the `eq` behavior by specifying the value directly. Note that you have to use Matchers for all values if you use any at all; you can't use Matchers for only one argument of a two-argument method call.

```
// Without matchers
when(yourMock.method(objectToBeComparedWithEquals))
    .thenReturn(returnValue);

// With matchers
when(yourMock.method(eq(objectToBeComparedWithEquals)))
    .thenReturn(returnValue);
when(yourMock.method(same(objectToBeComparedReferentially)))
    .thenReturn(returnValue);
```

If you *don't know the matching value until after you run the method*, you might want *verification* instead. Same rules apply about Matchers.

```
SomeValue someValue = yourSystemUnderTest.action();
verify(yourMock).initializeValue(someValue);
```

And if you need to inspect the value after the fact, you can use a Captor:

```
ArgumentCaptor myCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeValue.class);
yourSystemUnderTest.action();
verify(yourMock).initializeValue(myCaptor.capture());
SomeValue valueMockWasCalledWith = myCaptor.getValue();

// Now you've retrieved the reference out of the mock, so you can assert as usual.
assertEquals(42, valueMockWasCalledWith.getInteger());
```

Comment: Yes this will work if I know what value is created on the fly(to assert it later) and is used. But in cases of Calendar.getInstance; how I could know what will be the value on the fly, to assert against.
ArgumentCaptor will record the parameters used and let us know. I want to pass my value from test to the argument created on fly.